# ServerAlias not working | Apache 2.2.13

Tags: apache-2.2

I have this V-Host definition:

```
<VirtualHost *>
  ServerName www.example.com
  ServerAlias example.com

  DocumentRoot /srv/www/default
  Redirect 301 / http://www.example2.com/

</VirtualHost>
```

When I visit `www.example.com`, redirection works as expected, I end up at `www.example2.com`
When I type `example.com`, I get a 403 - Access Denied Page.

This is the relevant output of `httpd2-prefork -S -D SSL -f /etc/apache2/httpd.conf`:

```
wildcard NameVirtualHosts and _default_ servers:
*:*        www.example.com (/etc/apache2/vhosts.d/lnk-rp-www.example.com.conf:1)
```

I do not understand why and what is going wrong here.

Comment: Are you sure there is no other VirtualHost with `example.com` in the configuration? Do both addresses resolve to the same IP address?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for your hints.

Meanwhile it looks like I figured it out.

I had

```
NameVirtualHost 1.2.3.4:80
```

in my listen.conf.
Once I changed my Virtual-Host-Definition from

```
VirtualHost *
```

to

```
VirtualHost 1.2.3.4:80
```

it was working.

Thank you again for your help.

Stefanie